# Cannot parse JSON returned from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

In PHP, I have an Array of JSON Strings I need to return to JavaScript via an AJAX call. If I only have one element in the Array, I am able to call JSON.parse() on the response.

Ex (PHP):

```
$data = [];
array_push($data, '{"Date" : "11/11/2015",  "Number" : "123", "Status" : "Order Received"}');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Ex (JavaScript):

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Yields the following, which I can further process and display:

```
["{"Date" : "11/11/2015",  "Number" : "123", "Status" : "Order Received"}"]
```

However, if I push two Elements to the Array:

```
$data = [];
array_push($data, '{"Date" : "11/11/2015",  "Number" : "123", "Status" : "Order Received"}');
array_push($data, '{"Date" : "12/12/2015",  "Number" : "456", "Status" : "Processing"}');
echo json_encode($data);
```

I get the following in the Response:

```
["{"Date" : "11/11/2015",  "Number" : "123", "Status" : "Order Received"}", 
 "{"Date" : "12/12/2015",  "Number" : "456", "Status" : "Processing"}"]
```

When I try and JSON.parse() that, I'm blowing up on the double-quotes around the comma separating the two Elements.

```
}", "{
```

I've tried to address this in the PHP by encoding/decoding the Array/String(s) before sending the Response back, but had no luck. I also tried to address this in the JS by calling JSON.stringify() to try and reformat the Response, but no luck there either.

Wondering if anyone know the proper encode/decode/parse/stringify pattern to use.

Thanks for any input on this!

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue, `json_encode` should produce valid JSON, unless you're echoing and parsing more than once etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to populate `array` correctly before converting to `JSON` with `PHP`

```
$data = array();
$data = [];
array_push($data, 
           array( "Date" => "11/11/2015",  
                  "Number" => "123", 
                  "Status" => "Order Received"
                ));

echo json_encode($data);
```

This will give you following output:

```
[{"Date":"11\/11\/2015","Number":"123","Status":"Order Received"}]
```

Comment: Ah, I see, I need to push a new Array as each Array Element, not a String. Thanks much!

Comment: Exactly. The function "json_encode" translates a normal PHP array into JSON object.  You can use an associative array to create more complex structures.  WBR